# Open previous TabViewItems after page navigation of NavigationView class

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I want to save the opened TabViewItems dynamically, so that the user can switch to another page and return to his work, for example.

---

#### Problem:

[image: GIF - TabView]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add more relevant information with your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, I would like the TabViewItems that I have previously opened to be active, that is, to be opened again even if I have changed the page of the navigation class.

Comment: Have you read the link I posted ??

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

> Open previous TabViewItems after page navigation of NavigationView class

If you initialize the TabView's `DataSource` in the Page ctor, you could set the page's [`NavigationCacheMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode?view=winrt-19041) as [`Required`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationcachemode?view=winrt-19041) like the following

```
<Page
    x:Class="App19.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:App19"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    Background="Transparent"
    NavigationCacheMode="Required"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
```